# How to set aspec ratio with EVR in DirectShow?

Tags: video, directshow, aspect-ratio, directshow.net

I'm using a simple graph for video playback and EVR is my renderer. I want to force 16:9 or 16:10 aspect ratios at all times regardless of video and rendering screen native aspect ratio. Is there any way to do so?

I only managed to find [`IMFVideoDisplayControl::SetAspectRatioMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms704027%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but it has no option to set aspect ratio manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot instruct EVR to override aspect ratio, it only has option to maintain AR or not. If you want to change aspect ratio of displayed video, you have to workaround methods instead:

1. You can transform the video feed and change media type of the stream leaving payload intact and applying new aspect ratio in respective `VIDEOINFOHEADER2` structure
2. Or, you can disable AR maintenance option on the EVR and size it appropriately, having your AR in mind. You are responsible to letterbox the space possibly left around video in this case.

Comment: But can you actually set VIDEOINFOHEADER2 manually? I tried looking into it and haven't been able to find a proper way to do so. Can you point me in the right direction? Thank you!

Comment: There is no way to change it alone, since media type is a part of consistent filter operation. However, if you make a custom filter, doing it there is easy.